# SlideShow not running automatically

Tags: javascript, html

Good day Friends,

Can you please help me out. I have a slideshow of images (3 images).
It shows the first image when the page loads. And now instead of moving to the 2nd image it just shows an "empty" div until you click the next button.

The next and previous buttons are working 100%. But I just want it to move to the next image automatically after a number of seconds (10 sec).

### My CSS

/********************

```
*   Animation Styles   *
********************/

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 1.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 8.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 8.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

### My JavaScript

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

//I am trying to play the slideshow on page load
function autoPlaySlideShow() {
    showSlides(2);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length} ;
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].classList.add("active");
}
```

### My HTML

```
<section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
              <div class="slideshow-container">
              <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
                <img src="~/Images/Animation/img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
                <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
              </div>

              <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                <img src="~/Images/Animation/img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
                <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
              </div>

              <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                <img src="~/Images/Animation/img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
                <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
              </div>

              <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
              <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            </div>
            <br>

            <div style="text-align:center">
              <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
              <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
              <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

### On Page Load

```
<body onload="setInterval(autoPlaySlideShow(),5000)">
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you so much[image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps
https://jsfiddle.net/qsyLktdd/

this is what I have changed

```
function autoPlaySlideShow() {
    slideIndex = slideIndex+1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);
    //showSlides(2); old code
}
```

You were not updating the slideIndex after each interval call of this function

Comment: Hi Himanshu, Thank you so much for your help. Its running automatically now. Much appreciated. The only problem now is when the page loads, it show all of the them first, then after a few seconds it moves to the second image. But I will see what I can do with this one. Thank you again.

Comment: you're welcome. I think the second problem you're facing now is due to the reason that you are hiding the images by JavaScript in a loop. provide a default display:none on all except the first container and it should work. Tell me if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hi again Himanshu, apologies for replying late. I must agree that you're a genius indeed. I did exactly what you suggested and it worked like a charm!! Thank you so much. You saved me a lot of hours.